# How to update specific JSONB array elements in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

In a table (tableA), I have a column (columnA) type jsonb array e.g.

```
[
  {
    "pinned_at": blah.sdf,
    "pinned_by": "ford@gm.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": blah.dsf,
    "pinned_by": "vladyslav.kistruga@gen.tech",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": 1633874350.2,
    "pinned_by": "denys.voloshyn@gen.tech",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": 1625294401.79845,
    "pinned_by": "robert.john@google.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": blah,
    "pinned_by": "john@google.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": blah.dsf,
    "pinned_by": "apple@banana.com",
  }
]
```

A little bit unsure how to query for every pinned_by key. Ultimately, I want to update all the emails that are not google.com so that the end result would look like:

```
[
  {
    "pinned_at": blah.sdf,
    "pinned_by": "dasadgsf@googlefake.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": blah.dsf,
    "pinned_by": "dsfjldjs@googlefake.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": 1633874350.2,
    "pinned_by": "abcfjsl@googlefake.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": 1625294401.79845,
    "pinned_by": "robert.john@google.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": blah,
    "pinned_by": "john@google.com",
  },
  {
    "pinned_at": blah.dsf,
    "pinned_by": "asdinaof@googlefake.com",
  }
]
```

I’ve tried updating using this query, but to no avail. I feel like I’m close but am missing some specific value:

````
UPDATE tableA SET columnA = s.json_array FROM (SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN columnA->>'pinned_by' !~ 'google\.com"' THEN jsonb_set(columnA, '{pinned_by}',  substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 25)) ELSE columnA END) as json_array FROM tableA, jsonb_array_elements(columnA) columnA) s;```
````

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. Use a different data model - one that does not store JSON arrays or no JSON at all - and the task will become trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can build query like below (My sample table has `id` for group by and update record)

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5043c90ca61f94b8f1dae191bb6cde71)

```sql
UPDATE tableA u_a
SET columnA = tmp.json_array
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.id,
    jsonb_agg(
      CASE 
        WHEN e.value ->> 'pinned_by' !~ 'google\.com' THEN jsonb_set(e.value, '{pinned_by}',  to_jsonb(substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 25) || '@googlefake.com')) 
        ELSE e.value 
      END
    ) AS json_array
  FROM tableA a
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(columnA) e
  GROUP BY 1
) AS tmp
WHERE
  u_a.id = u_a.id
```